# Error using Rails 7 credentials system: `Encryption key must be exactly 32 characters`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encryption, ruby-on-rails-7

In the process of migrating an app from Rails 5 to Rails 7. Part of that process is moving towards the new encryption mechanism that is included with Rails.

I just ran `EDITOR=code --wait ./bin/rails credentials:edit` and tried to add some keys to the file. When I closed it, I got the following error.

```
/Users/YOOUSAH/.gem/ruby/2.7.6/gems/activesupport-7.0.7.2/lib/active_support/encrypted_file.rb:125:in `check_key_length': Encryption key must be exactly 32 characters. (ActiveSupport::EncryptedFile::InvalidKeyLengthError)
```

I looked at the `config/master.key` file that was generated, and the key is 32 characters.

I've already tried regenerating `config/master.key` and the `config/credentials.yml.enc` from scratch but deleting those files and re-running the command, but it produces the error.

I'm following this thread on Github as well: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/33528

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you aren't setting RAILS_MASTER_KEY in your environment via .env or otherwise.